# Installing Windows7 on a laptop that was on Windows8, then on Ubuntu

Tags: installation, 13.04, dual-boot

I bought a laptop, it came with windows 8. Horrible. 
So I installed Ubuntu. Then I couldn't access windows 8 anymore. So I played around and ended up deleting my windows 8.
I reinstalled the whole thing from scratch, only with Ubuntu this time.
Now, I want to install a "fresh" copy of windows 7 on another partition.
I created a bootable usb stick, but it won't load. It always goes straight to GRUB.
I did the boot-repair.
Well, now, I could pick someone's brain.
Thanks :) and Merry Xmas and Happy holidays!!

Comment: The question is confusing. A bootable usb stick with what? And what does boot-repair have to do with booting from that usb stick?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.
A bootable disk with windows 7 is what I'm trying to do.
I just wanted to point out the steps that's I've been through, by pointing out the boot-repair.

Comment: Is drive still gpt partitioned? If so you must convert Windows 7 to flash drive and add UEFI boot capability. Windows only boots from gpt partitioned drives with UEFI. Or totally erase drive and convert it to the 35 year old BIOS/MBR configuration and reinstall both in BIOS mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try another bootable program on the same pen or make a win7 DVD and try to boot from it.
So you can narrow down the problem

Comment: No DVD drive on the laptop. Startup disk creator can't load the iso file for some reason.. weird :\

Answer (score 0):

If your laptop is trying to boot from the hard drive ignoring the bootable USB drive, then either 1) USB drive is not set as highest-prority boot device in BIOS setup; 2) the USB drive isn't actually "bootable".

Comment: The usb drive is indeed set up as the highest priority list on the boot list in the Bios, and I've tested the usb on another laptop; it is bootable. Thanks though!

Comment: AH! My bad. I was sure I did that step. It boots to an empty Unetbootin screen on another machine. On my laptop, it is simply ignored.